# Xamarin forms tabbed page not retrieving data from in OnAppearing

Tags: xamarin.forms

I retrieve data from the Azure database to show one of the tabbed pages. when calling the method from ViewModel in OnAppearing not retrieve data, but when click the button it retrieves and shows on the page.

Please advice If I have constructed ViewModel and view correctly? if so why it doesn't work. ?

Connection manager:

```
    public partial class DatabaseManager
    {
    static DatabaseManager defaultInstance = new DatabaseManager();
    MobileServiceClient client;
    IMobileServiceTable<Person> personTable;

    private DatabaseManager()
    {
        this.client = new MobileServiceClient(Constants.AzureMobileAppURL);

        this.personTable = client.GetTable<Person>();
    }

    public static DatabaseManager DefaultManager
    {
        get
        {
            return defaultInstance;
        }
        private set
        {
            defaultInstance = value;
        }
    }

    public MobileServiceClient CurrentClient
    {
        get { return client; }
    }
  }
```

Model:

```
   public class Person
   {
     [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "FirstName")]
    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return firstName; }
        set { firstName = value; }
    }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "DisplayName")]
    public string DisplayName
    {
        get { return displayName; }
        set { displayName = value; }
    }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "LastName")]
    public string LastName
    {
        get { return lastName; }
        set { lastName = value; }
    }
   }
```

ViewModel:

```
     public class ProfilePageViewModel : ViewModelBase
     {
    DatabaseManager manager;
    string firstName = "";
    string lastName = "";
    string displayName = "";;
    IMobileServiceTable<Person> personTable;

     public ProfilePageViewModel()
     {
       manager = DatabaseManager.DefaultManager;
        this.personTable = manager.CurrentClient.GetTable<Person>();

        RefreshCommand = new Command(
            execute: async () =>
            {
                try
                {
                    await GetProfileAsync();
                }
                catch
                {

                }

            });
          }

      public async Task GetProfileAsync()
       {
        try
        {

            IEnumerable<Person> items = await personTable
               .Where(pserson => pserson.Active)
               .ToEnumerableAsync();

            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                FirstName = item.FirstName;
                LastName = item.LastName;
                DisplayName = item.DisplayName;

            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
       }

    public string FirstName
    {
        private set { SetProperty(ref firstName, value); }
        get { return firstName; }
    }

    public string LastName
    {
        private set { SetProperty(ref lastName, value); }
        get { return lastName; }
    }

    public string DisplayName
    {
        private set { SetProperty(ref displayName, value); }
        get { return displayName; }
    }

   public ICommand RefreshCommand { private set; get; }
 }
```

View:

```
  ProfilePage.xaml
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="SLSNZ.Views.ProfilePage"
         xmlns:controls="clr- 
             namespace:ImageCircle.Forms.Plugin.Abstractions;
             assembly=ImageCircle.Forms.Plugin"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SLSNZ.ViewModels"
             Title="Profile">

  <ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <local:ProfilePageViewModel x:Key="viewModel">

        </local:ProfilePageViewModel>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </ContentPage.Resources>

<ContentPage.Icon>
    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource">
        <On Platform="iOS" Value="icon-profile.png" />
    </OnPlatform>
</ContentPage.Icon>

<ContentPage.Padding>
    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness"                     
                iOS="0, 20, 0, 0" />
</ContentPage.Padding>

    <StackLayout BindingContext="{StaticResource viewModel}">
    <Label Text="Display Name"
               TextColor="Gray"
               FontSize="Small"                
               HorizontalOptions="Start" /> 

    <Label Text="{Binding DisplayName}" 
                VerticalOptions="Center"
               HorizontalOptions="Start"                
               VerticalOptions="Start/>

     <Label Text="First Name"
               TextColor="Gray"
               FontSize="Small"                
               HorizontalOptions="Start" />

     <Label Text="{Binding FirstName}"              
               FontSize="Large" 
               HorizontalOptions="Start"                
               VerticalOptions="Start" />

     <Label Text="Last Name"  
               TextColor="Gray"
               FontSize="Small"                
               HorizontalOptions="Start" />

     <Label Text="{Binding LastName}"              
               FontSize="Large"                
               HorizontalOptions="Start"                
               VerticalOptions="Start" /> 

     <Button Text="Refresh"
                        Command="{Binding RefreshCommand}"
                        Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>

    </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage>
```

View:

```
  ProfilePage.cs

  public partial class ProfilePage : ContentPage
   {
  ProfilePageViewModel viewModel;

  public ProfilePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        viewModel = new ProfilePageViewModel();

    }

   protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {

        base.OnAppearing();
        await viewModel.GetProfileAsync();
    }
  }
```

ViewModelBase:

```
 public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value,
                                  [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = 
    null)
    {
        if (Object.Equals(storage, value))
            return false;

        storage = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName 
     = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new 
        PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem

Comment: @G.hakim, Yes solved this problem by loan.burger. He gave me a nice example at https://github.com/loanburger/54430503.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view by the time you await viewModel.GetProfileAsync(); The view will already render.

Your GetProfileAsync in the View Model does an await so will get the data then update it.

I suggest changing the IMobileServiceTable personTable to a property and implement a on Property change to notify the view that the data has changes.

So your viewmodel should implement INotifyPropertyChanged

```
 public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
```

Then when the Data Changes you can notify it in the view model like:

```
OnPropertyChanged("personTable");
```

Also in your view change your code to:

pre-initialize the viewmodel:

```
public ProfilePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

         SetViewModel();

    }

   protected async void SetViewModel()
    {  
       viewmodel = await viewModel.GetProfileAsync();
    }
```

This way you wont block the UI thread and when you call the OnPropertyChnage it will notify your view to update.

**UPDATE:**

I have created a small sample Xamarin project for you to demonstrate how you can bind and notify the view of changes.

You had a few issues in your view as well where your DisplayName label was not closed properly and you had duplicate properties for HorizontalOptions in some labels.

Download this Xamarin sample. It had hard coded data but will show you the flow of setting the data and the Binding Context of the View without locking the UI thread.

https://github.com/loanburger/54430503

Comment: Thanks for your answer..viewModel have implemented OnPropertyChanged like ,  public class ProfilePageViewModel : ViewModelBase

Comment: So. ViewModelBase has this implementation

Comment: ViewModelBase have this INotifyPropertyChanged,   Please advice any wrong implementation

Comment: i have pre-initialized viewModel in view constructor, still data not appearing when the page load. This part OnPropertyChanged("personTable"); still need to be done. advice me . thanks

Comment: @rwahid after you have loaded your data which should update in the view try calling OnPropertyChanged("personTable") - where "personTable" is the name if the actual property you are binding to.  if you have a git repo with your code I can look at it and provide more help

Comment: thanks for your help. Please could you show me to implement this OnPropertyChanged("personTable") in my above code, that will be helpfull.

Comment: @rwahid I have updated my answer for you.  You have a few problems I have addressed.

Comment: Are you recommending the use of `async void`? Or is that a typo?

Comment: @g.hakim for this example and because he will make an api request to get his data I just added it in to help with OP's post. A task will block the ui thread if you await it in the constructor of the view

Comment: You cannot await something in a constructor, constructors cannot be asynchronous in the first place so how do you plan on awaiting it?

Comment: @G.hakim - by using async void... you are not awaiting it.

Comment: You can write an asynchronous task too! And not await it

Comment: @loan.burger Thank you so much for your help :) . According to your example,  modified it works. Solved my problem. Thanks for your awesome help.

Comment: @loan.burger basically here profile page need to show a person details when the profile page tabbed , so your code works fine , private async void Initialize(); this method initialize and get data using await call in the constructor, is this a right approach to this profile page ? i am not sure. Thanks

Comment: @rwahid you should not have an await in the constructor. you cannot await a async void as it does not return anything but the method will allow you to call your task to get the Initialize function and you can then await that. Good luck